# server-sided iteration through files in a directory

Tags: javascript, bash, cgi, iteration

In a highly simplified scenario, I have the following `bash` script running as `cgi`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"

list=
j=2
for i in $(ls *.log)
do
  (( j++ ))
  list="$list
   <a id=\"index$j\" href=\"$i\">$(basename "$i" .log)</a>"
done
(( j-- ))

echo -n "
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   title
  </title>
  <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5\">
  <script type=\"text/javascript\">window.count = {limit: $j}</script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id=\"list\">
$list
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
"
```

The script obtains names, base names and indexes (with offset) of all the log files in the current directory, and creates an anchor for each one. I would like to avoid unnecessary page refresh by changing only the contents of the `div` using `setInterval()`. Is it possible to do the iteration part using pure `JavaScript` (no `jquery`, `php`, `asp`, etc)?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. Have you tried anything so far? As in: create an `XMLHttpRequest` instance (aka AJAX request), use the `onreadystatechange` event to handle the response (which'll be the HTML string), and set the target div's `innerHTML`?

Comment: I believe you cannot do so, because of JS being client side scripting language which by design is sandboxed by a browser (typically). To be able to access your PC content (which may have different security level for access) you need something which is able to access your PC (like server side language or a shell script).

But if I understand your problem correctly you can write a small app which uses socket and use html5 socket to communicate asynchronously. That way you won't require to refresh the page once a new log file is created in the folder.

Comment: Yes, I tried `<script type="text/javascript" src="test.cgi"></script>`, but all the values are loaded on page load,  and I want to refresh only a single `div` every once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off don't [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Second, no your javascript can not iterate server directory.

You can, however, write a script which returns *only* the directory contents in a javascript usable format (json, xml, one-file-per-line, etc.) and then use that list to update the page contents without a refresh.

Comment: I wrote a `cgi` script that returns _only_ the `html` code that should be loaded into a `div` every _n_ seconds, but I don't know how to actually use it with `javascript`.

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Do you know how to do requests for data from javascript at all?